# Depricated method setCommandBehavior()

Tags: codenameone

Display.getInstance().setCommandBehavior(Display.COMMAND_BEHAVIOR_SIDE_NAVIGATION);
The method setCommandBehavior() above was depricated. The code is from SocialNetwork source code on GitHub. Am trying to understand codenameone by working on the given programs.
I have used the following code, but it is not working.

```
Form hi = new Form("Toolbar", new BoxLayout(BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
    Style s = UIManager.getInstance().getComponentStyle("Title");
    FontImage icon = FontImage.createMaterial(FontImage.MATERIAL_WARNING,s);
    hi.getToolbar().addCommandToSideMenu("Sidemenu",icon,(e)->Log.p("Clicked"));
    hi.show()
```

I need help solving this. Thank you!`

Comment: You don't need `COMMAND_BEHAVIOR_SIDE_NAVIGATION`. Side navigation is the default but uses the "onTop" mode by default now which is superior. What isn't working? Is there an exception or something else? Can you be more specific?